# Using Ajax to make add watchlist button feature (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My HTML Code:

```
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>

   // Same form as above
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  $.post(url, data, function() {

     try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").data('tooltip', data.addremove + " TO YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }

  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

`insertwatchlist.php` code

```
<?php
$response = new \stdClass();
$response->addremove = "item1";//you can get the data anyway you want(e.g database)
$response->watchlisticoncolor = "red";
die(json_encode($response));
?>
```

**Expected Result:**
1.)When someone clicks on `add_box` button, it submits the form without reloading the page (This one works fine)

2.) `insertwatchlist.php` sends this code: `{"addremove":"item1","watchlisticoncolor":"red"}` and, the Jquery code place them in place of: `$addremove` and `$watchlisticoncolor` variable, in the real time without reloading the page.

**Original Result:**

First point of expected result works fine.

Second point of expected result do nothing (no error)

Comment: Troubleshooting. F12, nothing in the javascript console? What about the network tab, do you see the network request being made? The die seems unnecessary. `console.log(data);` before your try. What do you get?

Comment: I would recommend not using `die()` to return something, per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php). I haven't tested it myself, but my first instinct is to try `return` instead of `die()`

Comment: No result in F12 console tab, here is the screenshot of network tab http://prntscr.com/fxntbs

Comment: Click on that request, and go to the response tab. Does it have the JSON you expect? What about the console.log result?

Comment: `response` tab?? Console tab is empty

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not defined at `$.post()` callback function. Though you have already defined `data` before `$.post()` call. Use a different identifier name

```
$.post(url, data, function(response) { // define `response` here
  $("button#addtowatchlistbutton")
  .data('tooltip', response.addremove + " TO YOUR WATCHLIST")
  .css('color',response.watchlisticoncolor);
})
```

`JSON.parse()` is not necessary. `jQuery.post()` converts `JSON` from server to a JavaScript object

Comment: Still, "nothing happens". No result in F12 console tab, here is the screenshot of network tab http://prntscr.com/fxntbs

Comment: Take his example and add a `console.log(response);` immediately inside the function.

Comment: @Toby The linked screenshot shows response is `200`

Comment: @Toby Note `data` is defined at JavaScript at Question, though is not response from `$.post()`, as there is no parameter at `$.post()` callback function. `id` in `document` should be unique; there are duplicate `addtowatchlistbutton` `id`s at `HTML` at Question

Comment: I cannot add different id's to each button Sir. Any Jquery solution?  Thanks

Comment: Sir, i am still learning Jquery. But i really need this code. Please help me when you are free, you will own me a big one sir, i need it badly. Thanks :)

Comment: @Toby You need to prevent the default action of form submission. Include `e.preventDefault()` within `.submit()` handler. _"I cannot add different id's to each button"_ The issue is not adding an `id`, the issue is elements with duplicate `id` in `document`. Substitute `class="addtowatchlistbutton"` for `id="addtowatchlistbutton"` at `HTML` and `$("button.addtowatchlistbutton")` for `$("button#addtowatchlistbutton")` at JavaScript